# PHP – setcookie() not working

Tags: php, cookies

I have this page that sets a cookie and echos out a string if you check a checkbox. The string prints correctly, but the cookie never gets set and I have no idea why.

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
<label for="checkbox">Option 1:</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
  <?php
if (isset($_POST['checkbox'])) {
  setcookie("cookie", "on", time()+3600*24);
  echo "You checked the checkbox and a cookie was set with a value of:<br>";
}
else {
  setcookie("cookie", "off", time()+3600*24);
  echo "You didn't check the checkbox and a cookie was set with a value of:<br>";
}
echo $_COOKIE['cookie'];
  ?>
```

Does anyone know why the above code does not work?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

PHP superglobals are populated at script start-up time, and then are NOT modified or touched by PHP again for the life of the script. That means `$_COOKIE` represents the cookies that were sent to the server in the http request that fired up the script. It will NOT show any cookies you've added/changed/deleted during the life of the script. Those changes will only show up on the NEXT request.

The only exception to this is `$_SESSION`, which is populated when you call `session_start()`.

If you need those values to be in $_COOKIE immediately, you'll have to add them manually, e.g.

```
setcookie('cookie', $value, ....);
$_COOKIE['cookie'] = $value;
```

Answer (score 16):

According to the PHP Manual at http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php:

> If output exists prior to calling this function, **setcookie()** will fail
>   and return **FALSE**. If **setcookie()** successfully runs, it will return
>   **TRUE**. This does not indicate whether the user accepted the cookie.

In other words, the function `setcookie()` is not working because it is inside the page. If you want it to work, you will need to put that function before the page, specifically before any headers.

**Do this:**

```
<?php
  if ( isset($_POST['checkbox']) ) {
     setcookie("cookie", "on", time()+3600*24);
     echo "You checked the checkbox and a cookie was set with a value of:<br>";
  } else {
     setcookie("cookie", "off", time()+3600*24);
     echo "You didn't check the checkbox and a cookie was set with a value of:<br>";
  }

  echo $_COOKIE['cookie'];
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>...</head>
  <body>
      <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
         <label for="checkbox">Option 1:</label>
         <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox"><br>
         <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. The question asked by Tim was "set cookie not working", and not "cannot access $_COOKIE value": the code given by Tim still won't work with the " $_COOKIE['cookie'] = $value; " trick suggested by Marc B.

Answer (score 5):

Cookies don't kick in until after they are set and a new page request is sent. This is because cookies are sent with page requests, they just don't magically appear to a the server.

Your solution is to do a page refresh after setting the cookie.

```
// set cookie
setcookie("cookie", "off", time()+3600*24);
// not available because this cookie was not sent with the page request.
echo $_COOKIE['cookie'];
```

Comment: How would I do a page refresh after setting the cookie? I don't think page refreshes can be done with php... Would I use `header` to redirect to the same page or use javascript?

Comment: You would use `header()` since you would do the redirect from the server.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I also faced that issue.
Finally got right solution.
Actually the third param should be getter then current time.
use like following:

```php
$my_time = 100; //It's in second
setcookie($cookine_name, $cookine_value, time() + $my_time);
```

This will work obviously.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. setcookie() must be called before any content is output!

```
 setcookie($name_cookie, $value_cookie, time() + $seconds_of_life_cookie);
 echo $content;
```