# How to access session or cookie variable on sub stores in Magento

Tags: php, magento, session, cookies

I am trying to access my session or cookie variables on sub stores but didn't get any values there.I am trying like this :

```
 Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->set("foo","magento");
          $_COOKIE['foo'] = "magento";
          Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setData("foo","magento");
```

When i try to access these variable on sub stores it returns empty result.I have created sub stores with multisite like `http://example.com/ and http://example.com/secrondstore`
I have created addson domain that link second store like this http://secondstore.com/.May be different stores with addon have effect on this

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of : [PHP – setcookie() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24662580/php-setcookie-not-working)

You will need to use PHP's built in method to set cookies: `setcookie`, then use `$_COOKIE[]=''`

```
setcookie('foo', 'magento',time()+3600*24);
$_COOKIE['cookie'] = 'magento';
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.But still didn't accessible the cookie on other site.I am using magento and i think they are creating new session and cookies on loading.