# Cookie value set not working

Tags: php, cookies

I tried many ways to set a cookie, but when I get the cookie the value's not set. My code is placed before the `<!DOCTYPE html>`:

```
<?php 
    $url          = explode('/', $_GET['url']); 
    $ref          = $url[1];
    $cookie_name  = "refid";
    $cookie_value = $ref;
    setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/", "", 0); 
?>
```

The `$url[1]` is set, I can see it in `print_r()` the problem is getting the cookie from a different page the calling code is:

```
<?php 
    if (!isset($_COOKIE['refid'])) {
        echo "<br/>Cookie named refid is not set!";
    } else {
        echo "<br/>Cookie refid is set!<br>";
        echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE['refid'];
    }
?>
```

Please help to resolve my problem.

Comment: To debug, open F12 in your browser, turn on recording and check to save log between pages.  What does the set-cookie header look like in the log?

Comment: it may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24662580/php-setcookie-not-working

Comment: Try this
`setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time()+3600*24); 
<?php 
    if(!isset($_COOKIE['refid']) &&  $_COOKIE['refid']!=null) {
        echo "<br />Cookie named refid is not set!";
    } else {
        echo "<br />Cookie refid is set!<br>";
        echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE['refid'];
    }
?>`

Answer (score 0):

Add this line:

```
$_COOKIE[$cookie_name] = $cookie_value;
```

after you set the cookie:

```
<?php 
    $url=$_GET['url'];
    $url=explode ('/',$_GET['url']); 
    $ref=$url[1];
    $cookie_name = "refid";
    $cookie_value = $ref;
    setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/", "", 0);
    $_COOKIE[$cookie_name] = $cookie_value;
?>
```

The setcookie() does not update the current $_COOKIE variable, which will be instantiated when the script loads. The variable will first be updated next time you load the script.